# Como executar uma procedure somente quando a anterior terminar?

Tags: delphi

Tenho 2 procedures, uma faz a compactação do arquivo e a outra faz o envio pro FTP, porém a procedure de envio, está executando simultaneamente com a procedure de compactação, e tenta enviar o arquivo antes da compactação terminar.

```
procedure TForm2.compactacao;
var
  sNomeArquivoCompactado, sDiretorioCompactar: string;
begin

  sNomeArquivoCompactado := ObterDiretorioDoExecutavel + 'setup/lib.7z';
  sDiretorioCompactar := ObterDiretorioDoExecutavel + 'bin\*';

  try
      ShellExecute(0, nil, '7z.exe',
      PWideChar(' a -r ' + sNomeArquivoCompactado + ' ' + sDiretorioCompactar),' ', SW_SHOW);


  except
    On E: Exception do
    begin


      ShowMessage('Erro ao compactar: ' + E.Message);

      // interrompe a compactacao
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
  log('Fim da compactação do arquivo de atualização');

end;




procedure TForm2.enviarArquivo;
begin

try        
if ConectarServidorFTP = True then
    IdFTP.Put(ObterDiretorioDoExecutavel+ 'setup\lib.7z','',False);
except
    On E: Exception do
    begin
      // ignora a exceção "Connection Closed Gracefully"
      if E is EIdFTPException then
        Exit;

      ShowMessage('Erro no upload : ' + E.Message);

      // interrompe a atualização
      Abort;
    end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código na pergunta, sem ele fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Mostre exemplos do seu codigo para a gente saber analisar e te ajudar

Comment: Adicionei o código das 2 procedures

Comment: Você tentou usar `TThread`?

Comment: Ainda não, @Sami poderia me dar uma exemplo?

Comment: Você tem duas maneiras, a primeira id para declarar uma variável booleana e verificá-la periodicamente, se o valor for "True", então execute o segundo procedimento, ou você pode usar "Threads".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este problema acontece porque esta utilizando o shell execute, este apenas chama a aplicação terceira, mas não espera o fim da sua conclusão. Visualizo duas soluções para seu problema:

1) Se utiliza uma versão do delphi mais recente pode usar a classe [System.Zip.TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Zip.TZipFile), assim é possível fazer todo o processo de compactação na sua própria aplicação sem depender de ferramentas de terceiros. Ex:

```
var
  ArquivoCompactado: TZipFile;
begin
  ArquivoCompactado := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    ArquivoCompactado.Open(vArquivoZip, zmWrite); //Cria arquivo zip
    ArquivoCompactado.add(vSeuArquivo); // adiciona arquivo no zip, para diretórios utilizar o método TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ArquivoCompactado);
  end;
end;
```

2) Se for obrigatória a utilização de uma ferramenta de terceiro para a compactação, você deve usar o método CreateProcess que cria um processo e consegue o endereço do handle do mesmo, assim você consegue monitorar se o mesmo ainda esta em execução com o método WaitForSingleObject. Abaixo segue o exemplo da utilização destes procedimentos, este foi retirada da pergunta [How can I wait until an external process has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336227/how-can-i-wait-until-an-external-process-has-completed), já utilizo ele na minha aplicação à alguns anos sem problema.

```
procedure ExecuteAndWait(const aCommando: string);
var
  tmpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  tmpProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  tmpProgram: String;
begin
  tmpProgram := trim(aCommando);
  FillChar(tmpStartupInfo, SizeOf(tmpStartupInfo), 0);
  with tmpStartupInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  end;

  if CreateProcess(nil, pchar(tmpProgram), nil, nil, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    nil, nil, tmpStartupInfo, tmpProcessInformation) then
  begin
    // loop every 10 ms
    while WaitForSingleObject(tmpProcessInformation.hProcess, 10) > 0 do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
    CloseHandle(tmpProcessInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(tmpProcessInformation.hThread);
  end
  else
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```